# Error filtering template: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

When sending transaction test mails like "New Pickup Order" we get the following error in the mail: Error filtering template: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again.

This happened after we deletes some products.

How can it be, that this affects sending test mails?

Any any idea how to fix this?

Thanks
Aldo

Comment: If you are trying to get the product that was deleted, then magento won't be able to find it. How is the product data being accessed in the template?

Comment: I use the standard Magento template. In it there is this placeholder: {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, while sending test mails, Magento uses the last order to fetch demo content.
As we deleted some products the mail template could not fetch this data.
We installed an extension to delete orders, after that all working fine again, as this orders did not contain deleted products.